# Java - Class that extends a class, and has a component that extends the other class' component

Tags: java, inheritance

To clarify, this is a Stack and MinStack.

They use StackNode and MinStackNode respectively.

I'm trying to get MinStack to extend Stack and MinStackNode to extend StackNode. However, when I do so MinStack uses StackNode instead of MinStackNode.

This is because Stack uses StackNode and MinStack inherits this. I want MinStack to use MinStackNode.

Organization:

StackNode -> Stack

inherited by the classes below

MinStackNode -> MinStack

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Code snippet for Stack:

```
public class Stack<E> implements StackInterface<E> {
    private StackNode<E> top;
    private int size;
    public Stack(E data){
        StackNode<E> node = new StackNode<E>(data);
        this.top = node;
    }
    public Stack(){
        this.top = null;
    }
}
```

MinStack:

```
public class MinStack<E extends Comparable<E>> extends Stack<E>{
    private MinStackNode<E> top;
    public MinStack(Stack<E> s){
        super(s);
    }
}
```

StackNode:

```
public class StackNode<E> {
    private E data;
    private StackNode<E> next;
    public StackNode(E data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

MinStackNode:

```
public class MinStackNode<T> extends StackNode<T> {
    private T min;
    public MinStackNode(Comparator<T> comparator, T data) {
        super(data);
        this.min = minimum(this.getNext().getMin(), this.getData());
    }
}
```

For space I didn't include some methods such as MinStackNode's minimum. If needed I'll include them.

Comment: Could you include a small, self-contained code sample that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Could you eleborate the differences between them and include the classes? You might want to override the methods and include a specific behavior for the MinStackNodes. If they differ to much in theyr behavior you might also consider to use a common interface for both classes instead of using one as a baseclass. It´s not clear what is actually a better solution to you given the information included in this question.

Comment: Downvote for not properly framing the question.Give some code so that people can understand ur problem.

Comment: As _khelwood_ and _Kevin Esche_ said, could you add an example of the classes instead of just describing them in text-from? With all the `Stacks` in your question I have the feeling I'm reading a tongue-twister like: `How much wood would a woodpecker peck if a woodpecker could peck wood?`..

Comment: The funny part was that I didn't include code snippets in the hope it'd be easier to read. Looking back through it, it was pretty incomprehensible. I've included code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if `MinStackNode` inherits `StackNode` then you don't necessarily have to include the variable `top` in `MinStackNode` since a valid declaration already exists in `StackNode`. However you will need to cast the value to `MinStackNode` when you need to use any of the non-inherited properties/methods.

I think your problem here is that what you expect to be of type MinStackNode is actually of this type, but is being stored in a variable of a more general type and so must be cast.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So if I wanted to avoid casting all the time I could implement as a generic, but it's just easier to do it and cast it?

Comment: Actually I would recommend using generic types rather than casting all the time. That's what they were introduced for, and they provide some useful features like failing at compile time rather than throwing exceptions when the wrong type of object is used. However having said that sometime generics can be unwieldy, and you are already using some generic types so I would say it's a valid design decision to avoid adding more. I think as long as the code is clear and casting exceptions are well handled you could use either approach.

Comment: Yup, I gave generics a shot for it and got so lost in the code. This entire thing has been so confusing. I tried using a decorator pattern, etc. Thanks for the feedback, I selected your answer.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps. If you want to go the casting route you could always override the getter method in the subclass and add the cast in there. That would at least ensure it's done cleanly. Once you have something working and relatively stable you can always go back and refactor. Maybe the generics will be easier to visualise on a complete working solution. Anyway, good luck with it.